# problems occur in jssor slider when getting multiple values(dynamic) using one div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jssor

here I use jssor slider and I need to get the values dynamically using one div(`slider1_container`) in php,

is it possible?

And I tried code is below,

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="category-box1">
                                <div id="slider1_container" class="common" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width:220px; height: 147px;">
                                    <!-- Slides Container -->
                                    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width:220px; height:147px; cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="imagecommon">
                                            <img class="img-responsive  center-block" alt="tour" src="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>media/images/category/thumbs/<?php echo $row['thumbnail']?>" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="imagecommon">
                                            <img class="img-responsive  center-block" alt="tour1" src="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>media/images/category/thumbs/<?php echo $row['image']?>" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 letter"><?php echo $row['title']?> </div>

                        </div>
                  <?php  }
                } ?>

<script>
     $(window).bind("load", function() {
 $(document).ready(function ($) {
    var options = { $AutoPlay: true };
    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
});
});
</script>
```

**Note:** In this code getting values fine,but problem is only one slider is working,
**I need all sliders to work,**
Is it possible how to get?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Different slider uses different name, if you name the first slider as 'slider1', please name the second as 'slider2' then.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="category-box1">
                            <div id="slider2_container" class="common" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width:220px; height: 147px;">
                                <!-- Slides Container -->
                                <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width:220px; height:147px; cursor:pointer">
                                    <div class="imagecommon">
                                        <img class="img-responsive  center-block" alt="tour" src="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>media/images/category/thumbs/<?php echo $row['thumbnail']?>" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="imagecommon">
                                        <img class="img-responsive  center-block" alt="tour1" src="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>media/images/category/thumbs/<?php echo $row['image']?>" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 letter"><?php echo $row['title']?> </div>

                    </div>
              <?php  }
            } ?>

<script>
 $(window).bind("load", function() {
 $(document).ready(function ($) {
var options = { $AutoPlay: true };
var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$('slider2_container', options);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I understand to add new Id,but in php its retrieve the overall value in database table, here I get only the title and the two images for all.
so each value display with in the slider1_container

Comment: like <div id="slider1_container"> title1 with below related two images </div> <div id="slider1_container"> title2 with below related two images </div>

Comment: can you understand my question?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what's the exact problem.

Comment: exact problem was i need a two or more slider using one id,
or is it possible how?

Comment: var containers = $("#slider_container"); var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containers[0], options1); var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$(containers[1], options2); var jssor_slider3 = new $JssorSlider$(containers[2], options3); ...